# Error while parsing procedure during Firebird database restore

Tags: firebird, database-restore, firebird2.5

I'm trying to restore database on Firebird 2.5.5 which was back up in Firebird 2.5.1

```
gbak -c -p 4096 -user SYSDBA -password "pass" -v /var/lib/firebird/data/db_data_201606150100.gbk /var/lib/firebird/data/db_data.gdb
```

I receive the next message during the restore process:

```
gbak: activating and creating deferred index RDB$FOREIGN97
gbak: activating and creating deferred index RDB$FOREIGN450
gbak: committing metadata
gbak: ERROR:Error while parsing procedure P_IMPORTTRANS's BLR
gbak: ERROR: function F_DOCNUM is not defined
gbak: ERROR: module name or entrypoint could not be found
gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors
```

I don't see any procedure and views after connect to DB on Firebird 2.5.5. It seems that db was not restore correctly.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by using an UDF (User Defined Function) in the stored procedure, for which the library is not accessible (either because it isn't here, it is the wrong bitness, or the OS privileges or Firebird configuration disallow access).

When the UDF is defined it is allowed to not have the library accessible, but when a stored procedure is created referencing this UDF, it needs to be present.

In other words, you need to find out which UDF library you where using on your Firebird 2.5.1 install and also install it in your Firebird 2.5.5 server.

UDF libraries are usually put in the `udf` folder of the Firebird installation, but Firebird can be configured to look for them elsewhere (`firebird.conf` setting `UdfAccess`). Otherwise you will need to drop or alter the stored procedure to remove the reference to the UDF and attempt a new backup and restore. There is - as far as I know - no way to skip this error when restoring (eg by not creating the stored procedure).